# AucTeX not loading beamer class

Tags: latex, auctex, beamer

When trying to use the LaTeX document class `beamer` with AucTeX it does not load the template. Emacs reports `Symbol’s value as variable is void: LaTeX-hyperref-package-options-list`  after loading `beamer.elc`. How can this be fixed?

If I type `\documentclass{beamer}` by hand and press `C-c C-n`, then AucTeX loads `beamer` (works for the whole Emacs session).

Comment: This is apparently defined in hyperref.elc, which should be loaded along.

Comment: @JeanPierre How can I load it along? According to Messages buffer it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you describe was a bug in AUCTeX which was fixed with [this change](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/style/beamer.el?id=c92251cb8dca5a35c818b0ce903277dd36e893ec).  This change loads `hyperref.el` when you request the `beamer` class and are asked for class options, making `LaTeX-hyperref-package-options-list` available before the style hook runs.

Comment: Thank you very much!